# Tool to cut small diameter PVC tubing/conduit?

Tags: pvc, conduit, cutting

## Goal

I want to cut a lot of 1/2" inner diameter PVC conduit (the gray stuff, not white). Caliper measured 15mm ID, which is really 0.6", but I think it's sold as 1/2", or maybe the fitting are sold as 1/2".

## Current Solution

I currently have a pair of ratcheting PVC cutters from `Harbor Freight` (my first mistake). They are horrible, they take a lot of force to make a cut, and the cuts are never flush (not that crucial, but would be ideal for aesthetics <sub>(I'm not using tubing for plumbing/wiring)</sub>)

I tried a pair of very similar pair of ratcheting cutters sold under `Home Depot`'s HDX brand. I borrowed it from the toolbox in the electrical isle at `HD`, so I figure it was well used (or recently replaced). It cut a lot better than my crappy `HF` pair, but it wasn't perfect.

## Ideal Solution

- A tool that can cut PVC tubing/conduit quickly
- Preferably with flush ends.
- Something that I can use in the field without a bench vice, so a saw is out.

## Considerations

I was thinking that a wheel-blade style tubing cutter would work well. I've used them on copper, and the cuts aren't always flush, but maybe I was just using it wrong.

Does anyone have experience cutting conduit/tubing with a wheel-blade tubing cutter ?

Or is there a brand of ratcheting cutter that I should consider?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PVC pipe cutter not working properly](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/40478/pvc-pipe-cutter-not-working-properly)

Comment: I like to play by `SE` rules, so I flagged this (my) question as a possible duplicate of http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/40478/pvc-pipe-cutter-not-working-properly but I think my question has merit to stand on its own. Plus, I didn't see the alternative question until after I posted this one.

Comment: I have used the wheel type tubing cutters to cut the hard type grey PVC tubing with good success. Be aware that there is a big variation of quality in the wheel type cutters available so beware. The really cheap crap ones let the wheel wobble from side to side so much that a cut that you may attempt will not stay in one circuit around the tube but will instead spiral itself down the tube. So pick out a cutter that has better quality.

Comment: I would not recommend the ratcheting type cutter for this type of tubing.

Comment: define " in the field". a bench vice is not necessary to use a saw. i have used a jig saw, hack saw, chop saw, reciprocating saw. i have held it free hand, clamped, secured with my foot against the bumper of my van.